# Intellisense XML Documentation for multiple variable declaration.

Tags: c#, intellisense

I have recently started adding the xml documentation to my code. 
I am trying to add it to code were I declare multiple variables in one line. 
Example:

```
    /// <summary> Integer1 </summary>
    public static readonly int integer1 = 0, integer2 = 1;
```

When doing the above it displays Integer1 for both of the variables.

I was hoping to do something like this.

```
    public static readonly int
    /// <summary> Integer1 </summary>
    integer1 = 0,
    /// <summary> Integer2 </summary>
    integer2 = 1;
```

I would like to do it like above so that I can keep the public static readonly above and keep the groups rather than declaring the public static readonly multiple times. 
It always says the xml comment is not placed on a valid element.

Is this possible to do in the way I want or am I stuck re-declaring all of them ?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. Declaring multiple variables in one line, while syntactically allowed, is not generally encouraged.

Comment: I figured that might be the case. Thanks for your comment.